# Understanding Gradient Descent Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

I'm learning `Machine Learning`. I was reading a topic called `Linear Regression with one variable` and I got confused while understanding `Gradient Descent Algorithm`.

Suppose we have given a problem with a `Training Set` such that pair $(x^{(i)},y^{(i)})$ represents (feature/Input Variable, Target/ Output Variable). Our goal is to create a hypothesis function for this training set, Which can do prediction.

Hypothesis Function:
$$h_{\theta}(x)=\theta_0 + \theta_1 x$$

Our target is to choose $(\theta_0,\theta_1)$ to best approximate our $h_{\theta}(x)$ which will predict values on the training set

Cost Function:
$$J(\theta_0,\theta_1)=\frac{1}{2m}\sum\limits_{i=1}^m (h_{\theta}(x^{(i)})-y^{(i)})^2$$

$$J(\theta_0,\theta_1)=\frac{1}{2}\times Mean Squared Error$$

We have to minimize $J(\theta_0,\theta_1)$ to get the values $(\theta_0,\theta_1)$ which we can put in our hypothesis function to minimize it. We can do that by applying `Gradient Descent Algorithm` on the plot $(\theta_0,\theta_1,J(\theta_0,\theta_1))$.

My question is how we can choose $(\theta_0,\theta_1)$ and plot the curve $(\theta_0,\theta_1,J(\theta_0,\theta_1))$. In the online lecture, I was watching. The instructor told everything but didn't mentioned from where the plot will come.

Comment: While you can use gradient descent - why? This cost function is convex and it has a singular minimum that is well known: `$\theta = (X^T*X)^{-1)X^Ty$`, where `y`is the values of train set (1xn dimension for train set of size n), and `X` is 2xn matrix where each line `X_i=(1,x_i)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At each iteration you will have some `h_\theta`, and you will calculate the value of `1/2n * sum{(h_\theta(x)-y)^2 | for each x in train set}`.

At each iteration `h_\theta` is known, and the values (x,y) for each train set sample is known, so it is easy to calculate the above.

For each iteration, you have a new value for `\theta`, and you can calculate the new MSE.

The plot itself will have the iteration number on `x` axis, and MSE on `y` axis.

As a side note, while you can use gradient descent - there is no reason. This cost function is convex and it has a singular minimum that is well known: `$\theta = (X^T*X)^{-1)X^Ty$`, where `y`is the values of train set (1xn dimension for train set of size n), and `X` is 2xn matrix where each line `X_i=(1,x_i)`.

Comment: I think the reason people teach gradient descent for regression is that if you have a very high-dimensional feature space, the closed form least squares solution is impractical because it involves a matrix inversion. That's obviously not sensible when you have just two features, but it's easier to understand the method when you have low dimensional space